# Reference to keystore crashes class initialization in Play! 2.0 (Scala, ~Java)

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

Using the awesome Java APNS by notnoop. https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns

For some reason when I want to pull in my keystore the entire object that houses the APNS just blows up. Here it is below:

```
object Notification {
 val iosApnsDist = 
        APNS.newService()
        .withCert("/ipush.dist.p12", "password")
        .withSandboxDestination()
        .build()
}
```

For those that are familiar with Play!, files added to the `conf` folder are supposed to be available on the classpath. So I was a little confused as to why my reference would crash the app.

Below is a snippet from the APNS java source where the keystore is pulled in. Any thoughts?

```
public ApnsServiceBuilder withCert(String fileName, String password)
    throws RuntimeIOException, InvalidSSLConfig {
        FileInputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            return withCert(stream, password);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeIOException(e);
        } finally {
            Utilities.close(stream);
        }
    }
```

### Update

I was able to extract an error message while running a try/catch during bootup. Basically, it can't find the file:

```
Caused by: com.notnoop.exceptions.RuntimeIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \ipush.dev.p12 (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at com.notnoop.apns.ApnsServiceBuilder.withCert(ApnsServiceBuilder.java:116)
        at engine.logic.notification.Notification$.<init>(Notification.scala:61)
```

I can confirm the file is indeed in the /conf folder, so what's the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of this. Take note that Play! adds files to the *classpath* but `FileInputStream` actually does not refer to paths directly on the classpath. Instead, it uses paths on the *file system*.

This previous StackOverflow will give the basics about **getResourceAsStream vs. FileInputStream**: [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

So going back to the original problem...it helped to have a look at the source code for the APNS. Notice that it uses `FileInputStream` but since Play! only adds it to the *classpath* then the source needs to be modified to use `ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)`.

I suspect this will also apply to other open-source libraries out there as well.

So why did the object crash? Because without a little error-catching it never would have initialized properly.